# Circular dependency with full type information

Tags: c++, templates

I have 2 classes, which are both included in variant. The variant is then used in both classes.

```
template <typename T>
struct Deferred
{
    typedef T value_type;
};

template <typename T>
struct DeferredContainer
{
    typedef typename T::value_type value_type;
};

class DictionaryObject;
class MixedArrayObject;

using DictionaryObjectPtr = Deferred < DictionaryObject >; // DeferredContainer<DictionaryObject>
using MixedArrayObjectPtr = Deferred < MixedArrayObject >; // DeferredContainer<MixedArrayObject>

typedef boost::variant <
    MixedArrayObjectPtr,
    DictionaryObjectPtr
> ContainerPtr;

class MixedArrayObject
{
public:
    typedef int value_type;

    inline void SetContainer(ContainerPtr obj) { _container = obj; }
    inline ContainerPtr GetContainer() const { return _container; }

private:
    ContainerPtr _container;
};

class DictionaryObject
{
public:
    typedef float value_type;

    inline void SetContainer(ContainerPtr obj) { _container = obj; }
    inline ContainerPtr GetContainer() const { return _container; }

private:
    ContainerPtr _container;
};
```

I don't know exactly how this works, but when I try to expose some properties on either array or dictionary via typedef (and use them in DeferredContainer), I receive error:

> error C2602: 'DeferredContainer::value_type' is not a member of a base class of 'DeferredContainer'

Can I make this work somehow? Any other ideas?

---

Update 31.5, 4:09 PM.

I have reduced the problem to its minimum. Hope this finally gets the attention. The [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30141fefd0a5dc1b).

After you switch the MixedArrayObjectPtr to be DeferredContainer, the code won't compile anymore.

Comment: How would `T::value_type` be declared inside T ?

Comment: For one thing, `Dictionary` does not have definition for `value_type`.  Neither does `Array`, so your `typedef` in `DeferredContainer` will probably cause a few issues.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you draw a diagram of what contains what and what points to what?

Comment: Just move the *definition* of `DeferredContainer` to below the definition of `Dictionary` and `Array`.

Comment: @fransian: I've added missing typedef inside Array and Dictionary.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Moving container definition below and adding forward declaration results in "uses undefined class Container<>"

Comment: `Array*` has as much static type information as `Array`. Unless you are concerned with the performance of dynamic allocations, objections to `Array*` seem unfounded.

Comment: @n.m.: Array and Dictionary act as a simple container. They can contain value of any object enumerated in variant Object - therefore an Array can contain DefferedContainer<Array> and so on. In dynamic polymorphism Object would be a base class, and I would use raw pointer to Object* as a value in both Array and Dictionary.

Comment: Is `std::list<Name, Object>` supposed to be `std::map<Name, Object>`?

Comment: @AndyProwl: It is supposed to be vector<Object>, my apologize

Comment: @Gotcha: Why `DictionaryPtr` and `ArrayPtr`? Those aliases do not seem to declare pointer types. Is it an oversight?

Comment: @AndyProwl: Hidden thing is DefferedContainer acts as a smart pointer, backed by instrusive_ptr. I did not find this information necessary for this problem

Comment: Let me try again. If `X` is a complete type, `X*` has as much type information as `X`, and you can use as much static polymorphism. Nowhere I'm saying anything about dynamic dispatch, inheritance or anything like.

Comment: I have to say that in my book what you do is not called polymorphism. Polymorphic software as I understand it is open to extension. You have a nice closed tagged union aka algebraic data type.

Answer (score 3):

I would propose just reordering your code to make sure that all the definitions are in the order that they are used in. We'll have to use `Object*` instead of `Object` due to the need of `variant` to have complete types:

```
// main types
class Dictionary;
class Array;
template <typename T> struct DeferredContainer;

using DictionaryPtr = DeferredContainer<Dictionary>;
using ArrayPtr = DeferredContainer<Array>;

struct Object;

// now definitions of them
class Dictionary
{
public:
     typedef int value_type;
     std::map<Name, Object*> list; // note Object*
};

class Array
{
public:
     typedef int value_type;
     std::vector<Object*> list; // note only one type here
};

template <typename T>
struct DeferredContainer
{
    // now can do stuff with T::value_type
};
```

And after all of that, we can declare `Object`. We cannot forward-declare an alias unfortunately, but we can just wrap up the `variant`:

```
struct Object {
    boost::variant<
        DictionaryPtr,
        ArrayPtr
    > value;
};
```

With that ordering, everything compiles.

Comment: It does compile, but the client is now responsible for the lifetime of those `Object` s, which was used with value semantics in the original design. Perhaps a `unique_ptr<Object>` would be a better choice, but I'm not sure. I am still confused by the meaning of `DictionaryPtr` and `ArrayPtr`, which do not look like pointer(-like) types to me.

Comment: You've made Object a raw pointer instead of value. Who will be responsible for memory free? Let's say, I'd like to have the Object a smart pointer - because this was the second purpose of my DeferredContainer was backed by intrusive_ptr. I did no consider this important, so I left that out for demonstration

Comment: The second major thing is, that type T::value_type for Object is empty and does not propagate value_type defined in neither Array nor Dictionary.

Comment: You can make it a `unique_ptr<>` - but you have to make sure to define the destructor in a cpp file - or a `shared_ptr<>`. That's fine. I just made it a raw pointer for demonstration. It definitely can't be a non-pointer-like type.

Comment: @Gotcha Huh? `Object` is a `variant` in your question - it doesn't have a `value_type`. I don't know what your comment is about.